# Webservice doesn't fire on host computer when using IP address

Tags: web-services, iis, dynamics-crm-2011, ip-address, publish

I cannot quite know what the problem is but I'll try to explain the current behavior:

I have a silverlight application that interacts with the CRM. On a  button click some data is loaded from the CRM.  This application is published locally on my IIS.

From the Host computer : 
 - I used the URL containing "localhost" to access my application, the button fired the webservice and the data was loaded. 
 - I used the URL containing the "IP address", but then the button did nothing at all, also no script errors appearing. (My question here)

From another computer on the network :
 - I used the URL containing the "IP address" and it worked fine

Can somebody point me on why I cannot use the IP address locally to access my application ?

Edit:

The code behind the button click:

```
   private void Contacts_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression();
             query.EntityName = "contact";
            query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet() { AllColumns = true, Columns = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string>(new String[]{ "" })};

            query.PageInfo = new PagingInfo { Count = MaxRecordsToReturn, PageNumber = 1, PagingCookie = null };
            OrderExpression oe = new OrderExpression();
            oe.AttributeName = "fullname";
            oe.OrderType = OrderType.Ascending;
            query.Orders = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<OrderExpression>(new OrderExpression[] { oe }) ;
            OrganizationRequest request = new OrganizationRequest() { RequestName = "RetrieveMultiple" };
            request["Query"] = query;

            IOrganizationService service = SilverlightUtility.GetSoapService();

            service.BeginExecute(request, new AsyncCallback(Contact_ClickCallback), service);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //this.ReportError(ex);
        }
    }

    private void Contact_ClickCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        try
        {
            OrganizationResponse response = ((IOrganizationService)result.AsyncState).EndExecute(result);
            EntityCollection results = (EntityCollection)response["EntityCollection"];
            System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<StudentClass> resultsarray=getTwoDimensionalArray(results);

            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate { EntityDataGrid.ItemsSource = resultsarray; });


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //this.ReportError(ex);
        }
    }
```

The function: getTwoDimensionalArray, simply takes the returned entity collection and creates an instance of class "Contacts" to hold the returned values.

Comment: can you ping the IP address locally?

Comment: Yes and I got replies

Comment: The html for my website opens when I use the IP address from my local computer, the problem is just when I click the button to start the service.

Comment: Can you post the code behind the button and isolate where the execution is different between the working and non working tests

Comment: I edited my post with the code behind, but i'm unsure about the part that doesn't work, I guess it's the whole things, I mean there is no response at all as if the button is dead.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a loopback check problem. See this KB article for details: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this sounds like it, but I cannot be 100% as I'm not receiving any error messages, it just doesn't do anything. This is not a private computer so I'm hesitant about altering the registries before i'm absolutely sure that this is the problem.

Comment: But both methods work when calling manually from the browser?

Comment: The Silverlight app may be swallowing the 401. Try running Fiddler (HTTP debugger) while your app is making the calls. Fiddler will show you the HTTP request and I'm betting you'll see the 401 there.